# problem with two select element next to each other when I use select 2

Tags: jquery

I am using the select2 library for two select elements beside each other. The first select element works properly good with custom js but the second one not working as I want. it works as livewire and custom js noting the impact on it.

my custom js:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="{{asset('js/plugin/select2.js')}}"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
            $('#select2-province').select2();
            $('#select2-province').on('change', function (e) {
                const data = $('#select2-province').select2("val");
            @this.set('provinceSelect', data);
            });
            $('#select2-city').select2();
            $('#select2-city').on('change', function (e) {
                const data = $('#select2-city').select2("val");
            @this.set('cityeSelect', data);
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
@push('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/plugin/select2.css')}}">
@endpush
```

**my code in blade:**

```
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" wire:ignore wire:key="first">
                <label for="select2-province" class="form-label">Province</label>
                <select wire:model="provinceSelect" class="form-control" id="select2-province">
                    @foreach($province as $item)
                        <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        @if(!empty($provinceSelect))
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6" wire:ignore wire:key="second">
                    <label for="select2-city" class="from-label">city</label>
                    <select wire:model="citySelect" class="form-control" id="select2-city">
                        @foreach($provinceSelect->cities as $city)
                            <option value="{{$city->id}}">{{$city->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
```

Comment: Is this at all a laravel issue? If not, please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve] with JUST HTML, JS and relevant CSS, e.g. RENDERED page. Please add teh select2 code from a CDN

Comment: in the first element this library worked well but, when the first select element onChange called, the second element is not select2 and seems wire: ignore not applied.

Comment: use let instead of const in `const data = $('#select2-city').select2("val");`

Comment: @this.set('cityeSelect', data); - isn't this a spelling mistake - cityeSelect should be citySelect ?